# how to duplicate the array values in javascript

Tags: arrays

input
var key=[
'id',              'name',
'health',          'status',
'environment',     'serviceType'
]

I am expecting the below output(duplication of the values)

[
'id',              'name',
'health',          'status',
'environment',     'serviceType',
'id',              'name',
'health',          'status',
'environment',     'serviceType'
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `spread-operator`:

```js
const key = [ 'id', 'name', 'health', 'status', 'environment', 'serviceType' ]

const res = [...key, ...key];

console.log(res);
```

Using `Array#concat`:

```js
const key = [ 'id', 'name', 'health', 'status', 'environment', 'serviceType' ]

const res = key.concat(key);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make with for as a solution

```
for(let i=0; i<key.length; i++){
   key.push(key);
}
```